# Jenkins retry block doesn't execute multiple times

Tags: jenkins

The retry block doesn't work. It only executes only once.

I tested the retry block with a `echo` and a `error` and it retries specified times.
But when testing `timeout` the retry execute only once.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                retry(3) {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                        sleep 3
                    }
                }
                
                echo "after timeout"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline-stage-steps-retry-timeout
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] retry
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 1 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 3 sec
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // retry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Timeout has been exceeded
Finished: ABORTED
```

If I try timeout 30 seconds and sleep 50 seconds, it still doesn't work.

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/5. pipeline-stage-steps-retry-timeout
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] retry
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 30 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 50 sec
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // retry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Timeout has been exceeded
Finished: ABORTED
```

Code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                retry(3) {
                    timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                        sleep 50
                    }
                }
                
                echo "after timeout"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you set the timeout for 1 second.

do set for at least 1 min or at least 30 SECONDS

```
timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES')
```

Comment: still doesn't work. Updated the log showing for 30 seconds and sleep 50 seconds

Comment: @John you didn't get my point. The problem is your sleep command is 50 Second which is more than timeout second 30 second. Make sure you use timeout second is always more than sleep.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a known issue, while using `timeout` inside a `retry` block:
[JENKINS-51454](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51454?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)
[JENKINS-51928](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51928)

you'll have to catch the exception yourself
here is a workaround to overcome this issue:
note: that the `try-catch` clause is inside the `timeout` block and not containing the `timeout` block

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                retry(3) {
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                        script{
                            try {
                                sleep(3)
                            } catch (err) {
                                error 'Timeout has been exceeded'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "after timeout"
            }
        }
    }
}
```